# how to make login module without create account,forgot password,forgot username in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5, jumi

I am using joomla 2.5,where i want to do admin login only, which will take login details directly from database.So i dont need the option of create new account,forgot password and forgot username option.

Is there any module which works same like this concept.

please suggest me any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla has template overrides.Overview:
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

As you haven't supplied template info - so I have gone with atomic template

1. Look for the module: "mod_login" it should be in: templates/your_template/html/mod_login/default.html -
2. For example you could delete the details below to get rid of:

   - forgot password
   - forgot username
   - allow registration

[image: line 57 - 74]

3. This is the correct way to disable user-registration:
   http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/users/disable-user-registration

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and tried your method but failed.
HOWEVER, with trial & error, I did the same coding with the file located in different folder. The folder I edited the code was ../modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php  and it worked
cheers

Answer (score -1):

In Joomla 3.3 there is no override between the core code and the templates code. If you want to disable such options, you definitely need to go modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php and comment out:

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=remind&Itemid=' . UsersHelperRoute::getRemindRoute()); ?>">
                <?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_FORGOT_YOUR_USERNAME'); ?></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=reset&Itemid=' . UsersHelperRoute::getResetRoute()); ?>">
                <?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_FORGOT_YOUR_PASSWORD'); ?></a>
</li>
```

Personally, I spent quite a lot of time to realize where the value of MOD_LOGIN_REGISTER comes from and finally, I realized that it is kept inside the en-GB.mod_login.ini, line 26.